# C# type system and dynamic type

Tags: c#, type-systems

I'm writing a paper about the C# (and Go) type system with focus on the dynamic aspect.

Does anybody have suggestions for papers/literature?

The things I found don't go much into detail. I would like to add some paragraphs on how it's implemented, comparisons with other languages, speed, memory allocation etc.

Comment: Pick the brains of Eric Lippert on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by reading all of Chris Burrows' articles on the subject:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031224853/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/tags/dynamic/)

Chris did almost all the compiler-side implementation of the dynamic feature and was deeply involved in the design process.

Also read Jim Hugunin's blog:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hugunin/)

Jim was the Dynamic Language Runtime architect and a member of the C# design team while we were designing the dynamic feature. There are not too many articles there but they are good for getting a basic understanding of how the DLR design process went.

If after that you have more technical questions I'm happy to field them. Post them on StackOverflow or use the "contact" link on my blog.